# Python: How to check unformatted mounted volumes that are named on storage drive

Tags: python-2.7, windows-7-x64

I'm using python 2.7 and am kind of new to it.

I have a device I'm trying to write a python script for that will check to see if the volume exists on the storage drive partition. This has to be very specific to check for volumes only (not paths and not just the drive letter). The volume has a name (we'll call it XYZ) and exists on the device mass storage.

There is a windows tool called DISKPART used in cmd. The long way would be to execute DISKPART with the script argument "LIST VOLUMES" and parse the output to a file. Then have python read and match the line from that file. I'll show you what the file looks like:

```
Microsoft DiskPart version 6.1.7601
Copyright (C) 1999-2008 Microsoft Corporation.
On computer: BLAH

  Volume ###  Ltr  Label        Fs     Type        Size     Status     Info
  ----------  ---  -----------  -----  ----------  -------  ---------  --------
  Volume 0     D                       DVD-ROM         0 B  No Media           
  Volume 1     C   BLAH         NTFS   Partition    149 GB  Healthy    System  
  Volume 2                      RAW    Partition      8 MB  Healthy            
    K:\XYZ\
  Volume 3     F   BLAH2        FAT    Partition     32 MB  Healthy            
    K:\BLAH2\
  Volume 4         BLAH3        NTFS   Partition   4608 MB  Healthy            
    K:\BLAH3\
  Volume 5     J   BLAH4        FAT    Partition   4256 KB  Healthy            
    K:\BLAH4\
  Volume 6     K   BLAH5        NTFS   Partition   1771 MB  Healthy            
  Volume 7         BLAH6        NTFS   Partition     20 GB  Healthy            
    K:\BLAH6\
```

As you can see, only the volumes are listed even if the volume like XYZ is unpartitioned. Is there an easier way to do this same thing in python, or should I start using the external tool (DISKPART) and re.search to search for line XYZ in the parsed file?

By the way, `os.path.ismount()` only checks the drive letter. I need it to read the volume name (not just the letter it resides in).

and

`os.path.exists()` only checks if the path name exists. It does not check to see if the path name is a volume or not.

Thanks in advance for any help given on this

Answer (score 0):

There doesn't seem to be a python built-in function for checking volumes inside volumes. So I have answered my own question with regex...

test.py file contents:

```
def check_mass_storage_dpp():
    with open('test1.txt', 'a+') as volumesFile:
        deviceMassStorage = 'Match Found'
        mainline = ''
        for line in volumesFile.readlines():
            if re.search('.*2.*', line):
                mainline = line
            if re.search('.*3.*', line):
                mainline = mainline + line
        if re.search(r'.*2.*\n.*3.*', mainline):
            print deviceMassStorage
check_mass_storage_dpp()
```

test1.txt file contents (this will be the parsed output file from running DISKPART script):

```
  gArbage1G@rbage    
   gaRbage2G@rbage 
    garBage3G@rbage  
 garbAge4G@rbage    
    garbaGe5G@rbage
```

Thanks